# Loop through an array retrieved from a hash table

Tags: arrays, perl, hashtable

I have a hash table with the following contents:

```
my %hash = (
  'a' => 1,
  'b' => 2,
  'c' => [3, 4, 5],
);
```

And later on I'm pulling `$hash{'c'}` into `@array_c` as part of fetching function such as:

```
sub getVar {
  my $id = shift;
  return $hash{$id};
}

my @array_c = getVar('c');
```

Then later on I'm attempting to loop through `@array_c` and print each line:

```
foreach (@array_c){
  print "$_";
}
```

However instead of the desired output of `345`, I get `ARRAY(0x100804ed0)`

Please help :D

EDIT:

If I do `print @array_c[0]->[0]` then I get `3`, so I guess I'm a little confused as to how I've managed to create a nested array.

SOLVED:

Went with deferencing the array:

```
my @array_c = @{getVar('c')};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sub getVar` returns a refrence to an array, just dereference it:

```
my @array_c = @{getVar('c')};
```

or change the sub:

```
sub getVar {
  my $id = shift;
  return @{$hash{$id}};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`[3, 4, 5]` is an arrayref, not an array. Modify your code accordingly:

```
my $c_arrayref = getVar('c');

foreach (@{ $c_arrayref }) {
```

Read [perlreftut](http://p3rl.org/reftut) and [perlref](http://p3rl.org/perlref).

Answer (score 1):

Just use the array reference as a reference:

```
my $array_c = getVar('c');
...
foreach (@$array_c){
    print "$_";
}
```

Or dereference the array reference stored in the hash, either in getVar:

```
sub getVar {
    my $id = shift;
    return @{ $hash{$id} };
}
```

or its caller:

```
my @array_c = @{ getVar('c') };
```

Answer (score 0):

A multi-purpose return for your `getVar`

```
return wantarray ? map { ref() eq 'ARRAY' ? @$_ : $_ } $hash{ $id }
     :             $hash{ $id }
     ;
```